# How do I properly set up a single-table inheritance structure using Ember's Active Model Adapter and Rails' Active Model Serializer?

Tags: ember.js, active-model-serializers

I'm creating a board game with a human player vs. a bot player, both types stored on a `players` table with a `type` column. Each player has their own board.

I have a Rails API using the active model serializer gem.
My ember app connects to it using active model adapter.

Here are my serializers:

```
class GameSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :winner_id, :created_at, :updated_at
    has_many :players, polymorphic: true, serializer: PlayerSerializer
end

class PlayerSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    ### Players can be type Human or Bot  
    attributes :id, :name, :game_id, :type, :created_at, :updated_at
    has_one :board
end

class BoardSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :player_id, :created_at, :updated_at
    has_one :player, polymorphic: true
    has_many :pieces
end
```

And here are my Ember models:

```
// game.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    players: DS.hasMany('players', {async: true, polymorphic: true}),
    human: DS.belongsTo('human', {async: true}),
    bot: DS.belongsTo('bot', {async: true})
});

// player.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    game_id: DS.attr(),
    name: DS.attr(),
    game: DS.belongsTo('game', {async: true }),
    board: DS.belongsTo('board', {async: true})
});

// human.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Player from './player';

export default Player.extend({
    type: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: 'Human'})
});

// bot.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Player from './player';

export default Player.extend({
    type: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: 'Bot'})
});

// board.js
import DS from 'ember-data'
export default DS.Model.extend({
    player_id: DS.attr(),
    player: DS.belongsTo('player', { async: true, polymorphic: true }),
    pieces: DS.hasMany('pieces', { async: true })
})
```

On the `games.show` route, I want to be able to call something like `game.get('human.board.pieces')` and `game.get('bot.board.pieces')` but no matter what I try, `game.get('human.board.id')` always returns `undefined`. I've also tried retrieving the board separately from the store, but the `player_id` is on the board, not the other way around.

Can anyone can help me figure out how to configure my AMS serializers and Ember Models correctly?

Comment: Are the correct API endpoints actually being called? I assume you have a `players` endpoint or such, but by default at least some Ember Data adapters determine the API endpoint name from the model name. It might be trying to hit `bots` or `humans` endpoints. You may need to create customized adapters for those models to force the correct API endpoint for them. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/models/customizing-adapters/

Comment: Yeah, I have both a `players` and a `humans` endpoint; both use the player serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up treating humans and bots as their own models since I would never really call `game.get('players')` this in the Ember app and it worked. Didn't have to touch the player, human, bot, or board models.

```
// game.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    human: DS.belongsTo('human', {async: true}),
    bot: DS.belongsTo('bot', {async: true})
});
```